# Debugging sharing violation

Tags: c#, windows, file

I have a .NET program that opens an existing file like this,

```
File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```

And it results in a sharing violation:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Since another process has already opened this file, how can I know the sharing mode used in the other process? I can't find that information with Process Explorer, any ideas?
2. There's no DELETE flag in FileShare, why won't .NET include that one like in the C++ language?

Comment: "There's no DELETE flag in FileShare" -- there is on my PC

Comment: @harold Not from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare?view=netframework-4.8.1

Comment: Well I don't what you're seeing, but for me the first row of the table says "Delete  4  Allows subsequent deleting of a file."